# Passing Parameters to a Report (Report built in parameterised query)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a report built on a parameterised query that requires quite specific variables so I have built a form with combo boxes to collect the parameters. I then try to pass the variables to the report, however, I can't get it to work and although the report opens, it keeps asking me for the variables I thought I was passing to it.

The parameters are taken from the form when a command button is clicked and the snippet of code relating to collecting the parameters and opening the report is as follows:

```
Dim args as String
args = "[Year Ending]=#" & DateSerial(Year(Me.comboYearEnding.Value), Month(Me.comboYearEnding.Value), Day(Me.comboYearEnding.Value)) & "#," & _
" [Budget Round]=" & Me.comboBudgetRound & _
" [Organisational Hierarchy Version]=" & Me.comboOrgHierarchy.Value & _
" [Nominal Hierarchy Version]=" & Me.comboNomHierarchy & _
" [Group ID]=" & Me.comboGroup.Value & _
" [Unit ID]=" & Me.comboUnit.Value & _
" [Department ID]=" & Me.comboDepartment
" DoCmd.OpenReport "rptForecast_4_UoW", View:=acViewPreview, OpenArgs:=args
```

This opens the report and the args string has all the correct values, however, on opening, the report asks for each of the listed parameters again and unless I enter them, the reports opens as with "#Type!" errors, I am assuming as the underlying query had no parameters to work with.

Could anyone explain where I went wrong and shed some light where the error lies.

Many thanks,

Simon

Answer (score 0):

First, insert `Debug.Print args` for you to study.

Second, the date expression may be formatted incorrectly, if Version is a string, it must be wrapped in quotes, and currency will go wrong if you don't have dot as the decimal separator:

```
Dim args as String
args = "[Year Ending]=#" & Format(Me.comboYearEnding.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#," & _
" [Budget Round]=" & Str(Me.comboBudgetRound) & _
" [Organisational Hierarchy Version]='" & Me.comboOrgHierarchy.Value & "'" & _
" [Nominal Hierarchy Version]=" & Me.comboNomHierarchy & _
" [Group ID]=" & Me.comboGroup.Value & _
" [Unit ID]=" & Me.comboUnit.Value & _
" [Department ID]=" & Me.comboDepartment
" DoCmd.OpenReport "rptForecast_4_UoW", View:=acViewPreview, OpenArgs:=args
```

**Edit**

It should read:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptForecast_4_UoW", View:=acViewPreview, WhereCondition:=args
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav, I checked the args using debug.print and that's how I know I'd picked up all the corresponding values. Also, as I do so much work transferring date values between Excel and Access, I learnt long ago to use DateSerial otherwise months/days can get mixed up. I can confirm the date is picked up OK from a data type of Date/Time. I'm thinking the OpenArgs must just create a filter rather than sending the values to the underlying parameterised query?

Comment: The following VBA code works fine when I open the query underlying the report from the same form, but clearly for a different purpose. I bring in the parameters as follows (shortened version of the code with only key elements showing):

Comment: Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qryDef As DAO.QueryDef
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qryDef = db.QueryDefs("qryForecast_4_UoW")
Set qryDef.Parameters("Year Ending")=DateSerial(Year(Me.YearEnding.Value), Month(Me.YearEnding.Value), Day(Me.YearEnding.Value))
qryDef.Parameters("Budget Round")= Me.BudgetRound
qryDef.Parameters("Organisational Hierarchy Version")=Me.OrgHierarchy.Value
qryDef.Parameters("Nominal Hierarchy Version")=Me.NomHierarchy
qryDef.Parameters("Group ID")=Me.Group.Value
qryDef.Parameters("Unit ID")=Me.Unit.Value
qryDef.Parameters("Department ID")=Me.Department  
qryDef.Execute
qryDef.Close

Comment: "_I'm thinking the OpenArgs must just create a filter_ " .. no, exactly not. Sorry, I didn't catch that. What you should use is not OpenArgs but filtering. I've edited the answer.